# tkinter: default values wont appear in entries even with use of StringVar()

Tags: python, tkinter, multiple-entries

My program is an IFS editor which has two windows: one for displaying a fractal and the other for working with the corresponding IFS.  The latter requires a grid of entries containing the values of linear transformations. Since I need 24 entries (6 entries for each linear transformation, and 4 transformations), I defined instead a table of entries using some for loops.  I know that I have to set textvariable to StringVar and use StringVar.set() for putting in some default values, but when I run my program, the entries are still empty.

This is what I have.  Here "matrices" is a 4x6 matrix of floats:

```
FunctionEntries=[[],[],[],[]]
FunctionSetEntries=[[],[],[],[]]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(6): 
        FunctionSetEntries[i]=FunctionSetEntries[i]+[Tkinter.StringVar()]
        k=Tkinter.Entry(window, width="5", textvariable = FunctionSetEntries[i][j])
        FunctionSetEntries[i][j].set(matrices[i][j])
        FunctionEntries[i]=FunctionEntries[i]+[k]
        FunctionEntries[i][j].grid(row=3+i,column=j+1)

    FunctionEntries=FunctionEntries+[FunctionEntries[i]]
```

The strange part is that when I defined some other entries individually, everything was ok.   Here were some of the entries that showed the default values correctly:

```
P=[0.85,0.07,0.07,0.01]

probs1=Tkinter.StringVar()
probs1.set(P[0])
probs2=Tkinter.StringVar()
probs2.set(P[1])
probs3=Tkinter.StringVar()
probs3.set(P[2])
probs4=Tkinter.StringVar()
probs4.set(P[3])
probLabel=Tkinter.Label(FractalWindow, width="15")
probLabel.configure(text="probabilities= ")
probEntry1=Tkinter.Entry(FractalWindow, width= "5", textvariable = probs1)
probEntry2=Tkinter.Entry(FractalWindow, width= "5", textvariable = probs2)
probEntry3=Tkinter.Entry(FractalWindow, width= "5", textvariable = probs3)
probEntry4=Tkinter.Entry(FractalWindow, width= "5", textvariable = probs4)
```

The last few were in a different window, so is that part of the issue? But everything else in both windows is running fine as far as I can tell.  I also don't see any difference between what I did here and what I did in the previous case (the order of the entry definition and .set() didn't change anything).  The grids also display properly.  The only thing wrong is that the entries are empty.  What's going on here?

Thanks!

EDIT:  There seems to be a problem with the double windows.  I defined FractalWindow first, and the default values for my entries appear in FractalWindow, but not "window".  On the other hand, if I define "window" first, the default values appear, but not for those in FractalWindow.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

FunctionSetEntries[i]=FunctionSetEntries[i]+[Tkinter.StringVar()] is going to contain a StringVar() 6 times, one for each "j".  If you use one list with 24 entries for simplicity to start out, you can just do the following (and note that you only have to keep a reference to either the Entry or StringVar, not both, to get/set the contents).

```
function_entries=[]
for i in range(4):
    for j in range(6): 
        s_var=Tkinter.StringVar()
        function_entries.append(s_var)
        Tkinter.Entry(window, width="5", textvariable = s_var).grid(etc)

## proof of concept when not using a nested list
for num in range(24):
    row, column=divmod(num, 6)
    print num, row, column

for row in range(4):
    for column in range(6):
        print "list offset for %d, %d = %d" % (row, column, row*6+column)
```

Comment: This does make the code simpler.  Thanks.  But I still have the same problem.  It is recording them; I use the function_entries[row*6+column].get()  and it does print the values. The default numbers are not displaying in the entry widgets themselves, however.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I needed to set one of my windows as Toplevel() instead.  That enables me to use StringVar in both places.  So something like

```
window=Tkinter.tk() 
FractalWindow=Tkinter.Toplevel()
```

should do the job.